# Videos played in fullscreen on Google Chrome forces window to be viewed

Tags: video, google-chrome, fullscreen

This is a strange problem that started today. The problem is as follows:

When I start a video in Netflix or Youtube and fullscreen it, either by double clicking, or by pressin the full screen button. Then, I change view by dragging three fingers from left to right or vice versa. A second after that, the screen changes back to the video. This is very frustrating since I want the full screen video to play *while* I'm not looking at it directly.

Oh, and it only does this when the other screen I switch to is full screened.

Other information:

- This is on a Macbook Air.
- I am using Google Chrome as a browser
- It works as usual with other browsers
- It doesn't do this when the video is paused

Thanks for all eventual help!

Comment: What OS are you using?  With everything you wrote, that indicates to me that it's Google that's causing this issue in the way they wrote their Chrome browser.  Have you researched this issue with Google?

Comment: I'm using Capitan 10.11.6. It seems that way to me too, but I have no idea how to contact google. If I try, I'm pretty sure I won't get an answer. I've been googling to the best of my ability, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? This is doing my head in as well..

Comment: I've had this on Sierra/Captain/Yosemite as well intermittently over the last 2 years and many chrome versions with all video full screen viewers I tried. Wish I had recognised a pattern.