# OSX / Chrome keeps jumping back to video when in fullscreen

Tags: macos, video, google-chrome, fullscreen

When I am playing a video in google chrome on fullscreen, for example netflix or a youtube video, my macbook seems very determined to keep me focused on that video. 
If I try to go to any other desktop or space by swiping left or right with three fingers, it keeps jumping back to the video. Sometimes this happens immediately, sometimes after about 10-20 seconds. 
It does not happen when I pause the video, as long as it is on pause I can navigate freely between all desktops. As soon as I press play again, it starts jumping back to the video no matter what I do. 
I would like to play a video on full screen while not actually looking at it the entire time. Sometimes I need to acces my work or chat windows at the same time.

It has been happening for a while now (maybe since I updated to mavericks, but I'm not sure). Other browsers and apps seem to be ok, no problem there. Does anyone have an idea what causes this?

**Information about my computer:**

MacBook Air (13-inch, begin 2014)

OSX El Capitan, version 10.11.6 (15G1108)

Google Chrome version 55.0.2883.75 (64-bit)

Comment: I have no solution, but experience the same on Sierra. I've tried opening the video in n incognito window, which did not initially help. However, as I type this, the problem is not occurring. Maybe you can test this as well.

Comment: Duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255962/videos-played-in-fullscreen-on-google-chrome-forces-window-to-be-viewed and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262646/chrome-on-macos-sierra-automatically-jumps-to-desktop-with-fullscreen-video

Comment: Possible duplicate https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108333/osx-keeps-switching-to-the-first-space. Apparently it has something to do with Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it will working?
Try to check the chekbox in screenshot below
[image: Mission control setting]